# How to separate words by uppercase letters?

Tags: php, preg-match-all, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, preg-split

I have string like:

```
SadnessSorrowSadnessSorrow
```

where words are concatenated without any space. Each word starts with a capital letter. I want to separate these words and select first 2 words to put in a new string.

I need to do this in a php application using `preg_match` function.

How should I go about it?

I tried using `[A-Z]`, but somehow I am not getting it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, we can also split our string by the uppercase letters, maybe similar to:

```
$str = "SadnessSorrowSadnessSorrow";

$str_array = preg_split('/\B(?=[A-Z])/s', $str);

foreach ($str_array as $value) {
    echo $value . "\n";
}
```

Based on [bobble bubble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5527985/bobble-bubble)'s advice, it is much better to use `\B(?=[A-Z])` instead of `(?=[A-Z])`, or we might use `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`.

#### Output

```
Sadness
Sorrow
Sadness
Sorrow
```

Comment: Nice one! See comment to other answer

Comment: Just fyi, you can avoid the additional check `if ($value != "")` by use of flag `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` or use a *non word boundary* (only between word characters) like `\B(?=[A-Z])`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer flashed once I posted the question:

```
preg_match_all('([A-Z][a-z]+)', 'SadnessSorrowSadnessSorrow', $matches);
```

It gives:

```
(
[0] => Sadness
[1] => Sorrow
[2] => Sadness
[3] => Sorrow
)
```

Comment: Keep in mind your code will not work with one letter words such as `I` and `a`. See here: https://3v4l.org/WBvLV . Emma's answer however works perfectly